# What is the correct way of using memSQL Connection object inside call method of Apache Spark code

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, singlestore

I have a spark code where the code inside Call method makes call to the memSQL database for reading from a table. My code opens a new connection object each time and closes it after the task is done. This call is made from inside the Call method.  This works fine but the execution time for Spark job becomes high. What would be a better way to do this so that the spark code execution time is reduced.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one connection per partition, like this:

```
rdd.foreachPartition {records =>
  val connection = DB.createConnection()
  //you can use your connection instance inside foreach
  records.foreach { r=>
    val externalData = connection.read(r.externaId)
    //do something with your data
  }
  DB.save(records)
  connection.close()
}
```

If you use Spark Streaming:

```
dstream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
  rdd.foreachPartition { records =>
    val connection = DB.createConnection()
    //you can use your connection instance inside foreach
    records.foreach { r=>
      val externalData = connection.read(r.externaId)
      //do something with your data
    }
    DB.save(records)
    connection.close()
  }
}
```

See http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#output-operations-on-dstreams

Comment: Thanks. I am currently working changing my code to use this.

Comment: This is for saving to external system whereas I require it for reading from external system.                                                                                                         The spark guide says 
"This function should push the data in each RDD to an external system, such as saving the RDD to files, or writing it over the network to a database." I require it for reading from external system. Thanks

Comment: I have updated the answer, hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: thanks. I want the code to do computation after reading from memSQL for each RDD. In case of insert operation it will work fine but in case of read operation it is not the end outcome it still has computation to do for each RDD after reading memSQl but the return type of foreachRDD method is void.

Comment: you can use `transform` instead of `foreachRDD` and `mapPartitions` instead `foreachPartition` inside, providing function `Iterator[T] => Iterator[R]` as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying this.

Comment: The issue had been resolved using this however it is taking a lot more time to run. Without using memSQL the events/per second for spark streaming is 3000. After using memSQL the events per/sec are only 550.