# Using memSQL with spark streaming has slowed down a lot, the Events/second of Spark streaming job

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, singlestore

I have a spark streaming job which accesses memSQL in certain cases. For the cases where it does not access memSQL, the Events/sec are around 3000. However for the cases where it is accessing memSQL, the Events/sec are only around 500. I am accessing memSQL as below:

[What is the correct way of using memSQL Connection object inside call method of Apache Spark code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36837588/what-is-the-correct-way-of-using-memsql-connection-object-inside-call-method-of/36839745?noredirect=1#comment61571508_36839745)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because you are establishing a connection for each partition in the microbatch. If you increase the size of each batch it will go faster.